# Riemann Integral of cos(x) from 0 to 1

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\int_0^1 cos(x) \,dx$ using Riemann Sum.
What i did

Split [0,1] into n equal sub intervals, [0,1/n],[1/n,2/n]...[(n-1)/n,1]
Δx=1/n

Sample points, $x_1*$=1/n...$x_n*$=n/n

Riemann Sum= $S_n$=cos(1/n) (1/n) +cos(2/n) (1/n) +...+cos(n/n) (1/n)

=(1/n)* $\sum_{i=0}^n cos(i * 1/n) = 1/n *(\frac{sin((n+1/2)(1/n))}{2sin(1/2n)}$-1/2)

I know the integral is the lim of the expression above, but i cant seem to evaluate out the limit and get sin (1). pls help, did i do anything wrong above?

Comment: You will never get $sin(1)$ exactly... You will be arbitrarily close to it...

Comment: which is the lim_n->infinity that gives sin(1) right

Comment: You mean you would like to understand why the limit of the expression you have given is $sin(1)$ ?

Comment: yes, i cannot arrive at sin(1). please help!! @JeanMarie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n}.\frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{n}))}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2n})}=\frac{1}{2n}.\frac{\sin(1+\frac{1}{2n})}{\sin(\frac{1}{2n})}=\frac{\frac{1}{2n}}{\sin(\frac{1}{2n})}\sin\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$

When $n$ tends to $+\infty$, the first factor tends to 1, the second to $\sin(1)$.

Moreover, by taking a first order approximation (beginning of Taylor expansion):

$$\sin\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\approx \sin(1)+\cos(1)\frac{1}{2n}$$

you know that the error is $\approx \cos(1)\frac{1}{2n}.$

Comment: Hi, I've heard that when n tend to 0 x/sin(x) tends to 1, does it applies when n tends to infinity too?

Comment: and thank you so much for yr clarification!

Comment: The property is "if x tend to 0, x/sin(x) tends to 1" ; here $n$ tends to $\infty$ thus $x:=1/2n$ tends to 0. We can apply the property.

Comment: I have added to my answer a precision (!) on the error.