# How do I prove that $ \int_a^b \cos(x) dx = \sin (x)|_a^b $?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

My Calculus 1 teacher gave an assignment for the class that I'm having trouble answering it completely. The assignment is to prove that:

$$
\int_a^b \cos(x) dx = \sin (x)|_a^b
$$

---

I managed to find a video from Flammable Maths titled "A RIDICULOUS LIMIT! The Integral of $\cos(x)$ in its Riemann Sum form!", which helped me a lot. The problem is that he uses the lower limit as $0$ and upper limit as $\pi/2$. I tried my best to generalize it to my case, but I'm stuck with this:
$$
\Delta b=b-a
$$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)\biggl(1+\Bigl(\frac{\cos\Delta b}{1-\cos(\frac{\Delta b}{n})}\Bigr)-\cos\Bigl(\frac{\Delta b}{n}+\Delta b\Bigr)\biggr)} {1-\cos\frac{\Delta b}{n}}
$$

I already tried applicating de l'Hopital on that, as seen on the video as the next step, but it didn't really help since it gave me a sign function according to Wolfram.

Any help on further steps is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981508/riemann-integral-of-cosx-from-0-to-1

Comment: Do you need to use Riemann sums? Can you use the fundamental theorem of calculus? If you already know that the derivative of sine is cosine, the proof is a direct application of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Sadly, it really needed to be using Riemann sums and from a to b (instead of from 0 to 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boils down to using the formula for a sum of cosines when the arguments are in arithmetic progression:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos(a+kd)=\frac{\sin(nd/2)}{\sin(d/2)}\cos\left(a+\frac{(n-1)d}{2}\right)$$
You can find a trigonometric proof on page 2 [here](https://evergreen.loyola.edu/mpknapp/www/papers/knapp-sv.pdf). You may also use complex numbers to prove it.

The Riemann sum (with left endpoints) is:
$$\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(a+i\frac{b-a}{n}\right) \Leftrightarrow\\
\frac{\frac{b-a}{n}}{\sin\frac{b-a}{2n}}\sin\frac{b-a}{2}\cos\left(a+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{b-a}{2}\right)$$
by applying the identity above and making a few simplifications. Now you just have to take limits and we can use $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$. We get
$$2\sin\frac{b-a}{2}\cos\frac{a+b}{2}=\sin b-\sin a $$